# session id changes periodically (nginx / tomcat / mamcached / MSM)

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, nginx, memcached

I met a problem when working on the group of servers:

- 1 - linux_01.xx --> nginx (proxy_pass)
- 2 - linux_02.xx --> tomcat01(8081) / tomcat02(8082) / memcached
- 2 - linux_03.xx --> tomcat01(8081) / tomcat02(8082)

the 4 tomcats use MSM (non-sticky mode) to share the session.

in those tomats there is only 1 simple webapp, ***index.jsp***
with only 1 line in the "body" node:

***<%= session.getId() %>***

---

now I can see the page:
        **http://linux_01.xx/s/index.jsp**

I just keep reloading the page by click the hyperlink. Everytime I can see nginx forwarding the request (I added some config for logging):

- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8082
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8082
- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8082
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8082
- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_02.xx:8082
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8081
- ....... forward to http://linux_03.xx:8082

=================================================

And the content of the web page everytime are as follows:

- 92DSAD8248237523875283723843-n1
- 92DSAD8248237523875283723843-n1
- 92DSAD8248237523875283723843-n1
- 92DSAD8248237523875283723843-n1
- MAS2983JDUEF83BF3NVDSN323556-n1
- MAS2983JDUEF83BF3NVDSN323556-n1
- MAS2983JDUEF83BF3NVDSN323556-n1
- MAS2983JDUEF83BF3NVDSN323556-n1
- 0928MSDHEW28JFWF2KEWM23FS-n1
- 0928MSDHEW28JFWF2KEWM23FS-n1
- 0928MSDHEW28JFWF2KEWM23FS-n1
- 0928MSDHEW28JFWF2KEWM23FS-n1

***Why the session id is changing periodically like this?*** should keep the same...

But it's not changing if we only have linux_02 or linux_03. It always changes if those tomcats are from both linux_02 and linux_03.

Would someone help me? I have spent much time on this.. Many many thanks.

Comment: Which version of MSM are you using?

Comment: staffs in WEB-INF/lib:::::   hibernate-3.6.10-3.6.10.jar --- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1-1.0.1.jar --- hibernate-search-3.4.1-3.4.1.jar --- javolution-5.4.3.1.jar --- msm-javolution-serializer-1.7.0.jar

Comment: apache-tomcat-7.0.50 used

Comment: staffs in $CATALINA_HOME/lib::::::::::    --- spymemcached-2.7.3.jar
 --- msm-javolution-serializer-1.7.0.jar
 --- memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.7.0.jar
 --- memcached-session-manager-1.7.0.jar
 --- javolution-5.4.3.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a tutorial about parallel deployment with Tomcat while studying a similar issue. Check out the section under heading ["With Session Established"](http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/04/17/tomcat-v7-parallel-deployment) and let me know if that helps guide you in the right direction for managing sessions across multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it by setting up a NTPD and NTP clients to make sure the time of those servers is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be caused by the inconsistency of the time (clock) between those servers, the gap is more than 1 day.

I resolved it by setting up a NTPD and NTP clients to make sure the time of those servers is the same.